# Android studio shortcut to go caller in Windows

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been searching for an answer in SO and Google but I couldn't find one. I would like to know if there is any shortcut to caller in windows.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

If I select `foo` somewhere in my code and click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> 
`Android studio` will redirect me to the declaration. But I am wondering if there is a shortcut to the caller object `foo`.

What if the object is used multiple times through out my code? Do I have to do undo each time then?

Comment: What do you mean by "the caller object"? Do you mean the places where it is referenced/used?

Comment: Yes. The instance of the class I use to reference the Class.

Comment: You mean go to useages? `CTRL + B` or `CMD + B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-------------On Windows------------------------**
**Press and hold CTRL + Click on the object.**
**-------------On Mac------------------------**
**Press and hold Apple Key(IDK what that key is called)+Click on the Object.**

If you click on the declaration it will show you the Usages of the particular object in the entire project. If you click on the object(Any of the usages), then it will direct you to the declaration of the object.
Eg :: If you click on a method name(in the declaration/definition) then AS will show you the usages of that function.
If you click on the method name(except in the definition), AS will take you to the declaration/definition of that method.

Answer (score 3):

***Go to implementation***

*For Window*

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

*For Mac*

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

[shortcuts detail](http://www.developerphil.com/android-studio-tips-of-the-day-roundup-1/)